# Insertar Layout's en ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xml

Dispongo de una actividad que en la parte inferior de la misma cargo un ViewPager donde tengo intención de añadirle un edit-text y un par de botones.

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// List of fragments which are going to set in the view pager widget
List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param fm interface for interacting with Fragment objects inside of an
 *           Activity
 */
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
}

/**
 * Add a new fragment in the list.
 *
 * @param fragment a new fragment
 */
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Página " + (position + 1);
}
}
```

Actualmente dispongo de cuatro pages donde cargo un color de fondo y un texto de esta forma.

```
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.positivo), 0));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.negativo), 1));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.positivo), 2));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.negativo), 3));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.positivo), 4));
    this.pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Esto lo realizo en el fichero java de la actividad donde quiero que se ejecute el ViewPager.

Tengo dos dudas: ¿como quedaría un xml de prueba donde apareciese dos botones y un edit_text en un fichero drawable resource file? y ¿como puedo cargar ese xml generado, en el fichero java donde establezco el contenido del ViewPager si se encontrase en la carpeta drawable?

Comment: Puedes mirarte este gist https://gist.github.com/webserveis/118d012f4f17deb9fe042b0eeb7fc392

Comment: En tu caso al fragmento ScreenSlidePageFragment puedes cargar el fragment dependiendo del posición, le pasas como argumento de la segunda posición. Allí puedes determinar cargar uno o otro

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer en cada creación del fragmento importe e layout propio, dependiendo de la posición cargas un fragmento o otro.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de armar un `ViewPager` de 3 fragmentos individuales.

```
public class DemoFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public DemoFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return ThirdFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
}
```

En el `getItem` es donde especificas que `Fragment` debe cargar dependiendo de su posición dentro del `ViewPager`

Puedes crear el fragmento individualmente, como puedes ver en el `onCreateView` es donde cargas el `layout.xml` correspondiente.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Finalmente establecer el `Adapter` al `ViewPager`

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
DemoFragmentAdapter adapterViewPager = new DemoFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
```